# Jackson-all download for 2.x versions

Tags: java, jackson

Where can I download the Jackson (JSON) library's JAR named `jackson-all` for the 2.x versions, say for 2.5 or 2.5.2?

Comment: Have you even tried to Google it?

Comment: There isn't any `jackson-all` for 2.5. Use maven and e.g. `com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind`

Comment: @JaredBurrows Yes. How about you?

Comment: @beerbajay Hm, so I thought too, I just wasn't sure. Thanks.

Comment: The reason I asked is because you are looking for a library. Why not add the jars you need? Preferable using Maven or Gradle.

Comment: @JaredBurrows I needed a jar so I asked for a jar. Plain and simple. Why not blah-blah... I have no time and space to write a novel here about why this and why that. Sorry but such comments are counter productive. Why not answer the question, or just take no action, instead of leaving such why-not-type-of-comments which are not helpful?

Comment: Based on your current -1 and the upvotes on my question, I suggest you read my comments for a second time. I said `Why not add the jars you need`. You will **have** to do this anyway since there is no `jackson-all` for `2.x`+.

Comment: @JaredBurrows Never mind, thanks anyway. I'm all set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no `<...>-all.jar` for Jackson 2.x.

Just add these JARs:

`jackson-annotations-<version>.jar`
`jackson-core-<version>.jar`
`jackson-databind-<version>.jar`